# Tourist Natives Model

Tags: industrial-organisation

Every night, all 60 inhabitants of a tiny village visit one of the village’s taverns (not necessarily the same tavern) and an average of 75 strangers do the same. Both the villagers and the strangers are willing to pay up to $3 for a drink, and no one ever buys more than one. But, whereas the strangers pick any tavern at random, the villagers compare prices and go to the cheapest. The market is in free-entry equilibrium and each tavern’s costs of providing q drinks a night are C(q) = 36.75 +0.1q +0.03q^2. What do the taverns charge for a drink?

I have solved this question but couldn't understand why in the end there were 3 low price and 2 high price taverns? How do I figure out how many low price and high price taverns there is? Is there a method?